# How do I update useState object array instead of adding new array element in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, react-context

I have a useState object something like

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
  dish: "",
  category: "",
  cost: 0,
  qnty: 0,
  img: "",
})
```

Here `qnty` is a counter variable. Everytime the counter is updated, `data` obj too is updated. Every time `data` is updated, `updateCart` function is called and the values in the context state are updated.
Here is the context state

```
state = {
  updateCart: this.updateCart,
  cart: [
      {
        dish: "",
        category: "",
        cost: 0,
        qnty: 0,
        img: "",
      }
    ]
```

`updateCart` function

```
  updateCart = (newItem) => {
    this.setState({
      cart: [newItem, ...this.state.cart],
    });
  };
```

The function is working perfectly fine. A new array is being added, that's good. But, since the `qnty` is a counter, I want to update the `cart` array in the context state every time `updateCart` is called, instead of adding a new row for the updated `qnty`.

Just for example, if the `cart` already has an element (object) with `qnty` as 1, and if I change the `qnty` to 2, a new element is added into the `cart` array. Instead, I want to update the existing 1 to 2.

How do I do that?

This is what i've tried at `updateCart` function

```
updateCart = (newItem) => {
    if (
      this.state.cart.filter(
        (element) => element.dish === newItem.dish && element.dish !== ""
      ).length > 0
    ) {
      const indx = this.state.cart.findIndex(
        (element) => element.dish === newItem.dish
      );
      this.state.cart[indx].qnty = newItem.qnty;
    } else {
      this.setState({
        cart: [newItem, ...this.state.cart],
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: Just like you'd expect, with the caveat that you still want to return a new array so React understands that the state has been updated.

Comment: so...is there any other alternative? I am trying to build a grocery app, with a cart. User can select the quantity of that item through a button (more like a button group) so, i want to store this data in the context state so that i can access the cart data from anywhere.

Comment: @KaustubhPaturi: Well, currently the logic shown is to always add an element to the `cart` array.  If instead you want to check if a matching element already exists in the `cart` array and update that element instead, you'd do exactly that.  So before setting state, you'd look for a matching element in the array.  If one is found, make a local copy of that element and update that local copy as needed.  Then set state to a new array composed of the updated local copy and the existing array elements which don't match.

Comment: What unique about the items, is it `dish`?.  IOW: if you add a dish you already have in the array, it will add the `qnty`'s together?

Comment: @David I've tried that, but I wasn't able to come up with a logic. Could you help?

Comment: @Keith yup, `dish` is unique. And when a new object is entered, it wont update the `qnty` if the `dish` is already present. I need to check if the `dish` is already present or not.

Comment: @KaustubhPaturi: What specifically did you try?  What specifically didn't work as expected?  Please update the question to include your attempt and information about the problem.

Comment: @KaustubhPaturi There's no real "logic": find the matching item. Update its quantity. Create a new array with the existing elements, replacing the updated element with the updated element.

Comment: `this.setState`, `state = {`,   You certainly want to avoid doing that, your using global var here.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Do check out the question, I've now updated it with what I've tried.

Comment: @Keith: I didn't get you

Comment: @KaustubhPaturi: This certainly won't work: `this.state.cart[indx].qnty = newItem.qnty;`  You're *mutating* state instead of updating it.  Note how the "working" code calls `this.setState()`.  Any time you want to update state, you would call that.

Comment: @KaustubhPaturi `this.state.cart[indx].qnty = newItem.qnty` modifies state directly. The item being updated needs to be added to a new array containing all the existing state, replacing the updated item with the new item.

Comment: @David With the caveat that the state needs to be set with a new array, not just re-setting the state w/ the existing array with one of its elements modified.

Comment: `state = {`  whenever you assign to var, without putting either.  `const / let` or even `var` in front, it will create a global variable.  To be fair it might just be copy / paste error, but with you also using `this`, for React Hooks is also odd.

Comment: @Keith I think the OP is showing what the state is. All the code uses `this.setState`.

Comment: @DaveNewton   That was my point, what is `this`,  hooks are pure functions not classes, so I'm a little confused why he's even got `this` in any of his code.

Comment: @Keith Oh, wait; I see what you mean--nvm.

Comment: Got you @David, got where I'm going wrong...Thanks mate!

Comment: @Keith: This is a class component, not a functional component, so having `this` to access the elements is necessary

Comment: Hey...thank you everyone, for helpinng me finding an answer for this. I just posted my answer. Could you go through it and if you find something, do suggest! Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

Updating the `updateCart` function with this helps solving the problem

```
  updateCart = (newItem) => {
    if (
      this.state.cart.filter(
        (element) => element.dish === newItem.dish && element.dish !== ""
      ).length > 0
    ) {
      // console.log("inside if");
      const indx = this.state.cart.findIndex(
        (element) => element.dish === newItem.dish
      );
      this.setState(() => {
        this.state.cart[indx].qnty = newItem.qnty;
        // this.state.cart.slice(2);
      });
    } else {
      // console.log("inside else");
      this.setState({
        cart: [...this.state.cart, newItem],
      });
    }
    // console.log(this.state.cart.slice(2));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't updating state:

```
this.state.cart[indx].qnty = newItem.qnty;
```

This is *mutating* state, which is bad for a variety of reasons.  Note how you call `this.setState()` to *update* state in your working version:

```
this.setState({
  cart: [newItem, ...this.state.cart],
});
```

Whether you're updating an existing array element or adding a new one, the operation to *update state* doesn't change.  All that changes is how you construct the new array to send to state.

In general the logic for updating an existing item vs. adding a new one would be something like:

```
- search for a matching existing item
- if one is found
  - create a new shallow copy of that item, updating data as needed
  - set state to a new array containing the copy of the item and all existing items *except* the matching one
- else
  - set state to a new array containing a new item and all existing items
```

In both cases it's critical to note that state is being set to a *new* array, not just modifying the existing one.

An example of this logic could be something like:

```
updateCart = (newItem) => {
  if (this.state.cart.find(c => c.dish === newItem.dish && c.dish !== "")) {
    this.setState({
      cart: [...this.state.cart.map(c => {
        if (c.dish === newItem.dish && c.dish !== "") {
          return { ...c, qnty: newItem.qnty }
        } else {
          return c;
        }
      })],
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      cart: [newItem, ...this.state.cart],
    });
  }
};
```

The main difference (other than shortening your `if` condition from `filter` to `find` and a shorter variable name to reduce clutter) is the use of `.map()` when setting state for cases where the element exists.

Overall `.map()` returns a new array, so it's safe for setting state in this manner.  And it preserves the current order of the array.  The callback to `.map()` here simply checks if the current element matches the condition and, if so, returns a new element with the same values plus the one updated value.  For all other elements it returns the element as-is.

Comment: thank you so much man, sure it works fine and thank you for making it much more efficient than before!